# How to use multiple datasets in one go with Typeahead and Bloodhound?

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm trying to use Typeahead/Bloodhound for suggestions and search. For simplicity's sake, let's assume I have two types of model objects - **Country** and **City**.

```
public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(Server-side is in ASP.NET, but that's irrelevant for the question).

City is practically the same as Country, except with a different name.

Anyway, before styling, I expect the end result to look like this:

[image: bloodhound multiple datasets]

(If it's not obvious, I've written "AL" in the textbox, the remaining letters form the first suggestion)

And I'm able to achieve this easily by using multiple Bloodhounds:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 5,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/countries/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});

var cities = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 5,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/cities/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

and multiple input objects to typeahead:

```
$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null,
    {
        name: 'countries',
        display: 'name',
        source: countries,
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'unable to find any countries that match the current query',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{name}}</strong></div>'),
            header: '<h2>Countries</h2>'
        }

    },
    {
        name: 'cities',
        display: 'name',
        source: cities,
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                'unable to find any cities that match the current query',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{name}}</strong></div>'),
            header: '<h2>Cities</h2>'
        }

    });
```

However, in my real-world scenario, I have about 10 datasets. Creating 10 separate queries, combined with JSON serialization/deserialization sould probably kill my servers on the spot, especially with multiple users.

What I'd prefer is to have a composite DTO:

```
public class CompositeSearchResult
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    //... and many others
}
```

... while somehow handling the complex object on the client with Bloodhound. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did it!

First I found out, that Bloodhound caching is smart - so if a search query has already been conducted by it, it will no longer use the network - and will look in the cache instead.

So this means that if the URL for both datasets is the same, the query is only performed once on the server, and the result set is then cached and used by all bloodhounds.

Going back to the simple Countries+Cities example, it should look like this:

```
var countries = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 5,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/compositesearch/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        transform: function(d) {
            return d.countries;
        }
    }
});

var cities = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 5,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/compositesearch/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        transform: function(d) {
            return d.cities;
        }
    }
});
```

The only difference in both cases is the "transform" function in the **remote** settings.

Then, by using the exact same CompositeSearch object from the question, I'm able to retrieve both datasets (essentially the same as in the screenshot) at one go instead of 2 - confirmed by the Network tab of my browser :)